# How to make Google Earth circular sector for certain radius and bearing

Tags: google-earth

I would like to make a polygon (circular sector) with a certain angle and radius from a bunch of latitudes/longitudes.

[image]
<sup>**semicircle using geodesic points between 2 latitudes and longitudes**</sup>

Comment: People who might be able to tell you how to do this may be unfamiliar with the terminology.  If you expand the question to better describe what you want (in more generic terms, maybe include some reference links), you are likely to get a better response.  Also, you had some Excel tags before the edit.  How did you envision that relating?

Comment: In Google Earth, the Ruler tool gives you bearing and distance from a point. Please comment and provide information about if my edit is correct or not, so I can edit your question to make it more accurate and easier to understand.